# ExtJS callParent on messageBox show method not working

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, extjs

On ExtJS 6.02, I have this code:

```js
Ext.define('MyDialog', {
     extend : 'Ext.window.MessageBox'
   , title : 'My title'
   , closable : false
   , buttonText : {
        ok     : 'Yes'
      , yes    : 'Yep'
      , no     : 'No way'
      , cancel : 'Cancel'
   }
   , show: function(cfg) {
      cfg = {
           icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION
         , msg : 'test'
         , buttons : Ext.Msg.OKCANCEL
      };

      this.callParent(cfg);
   }
});
```

The popup appears in blank, it seems that `cfg` is not being passed to the parent class method!

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3deb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The parameter of callParent must be an arrayLike type because internally ExtJS uses `Function.prototype.apply()`.

So this works:

```
Ext.define('MyDialog', {
     extend : 'Ext.window.MessageBox'
   , title : 'My title'
   , closable : false
   , buttonText : {
        ok     : 'Yes'
      , yes    : 'Yep'
      , no     : 'No way'
      , cancel : 'Cancel'
   }
   , show: function(cfg) {
      cfg = {
           icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION
         , msg : 'test'
         , buttons : Ext.Msg.OKCANCEL
      };

      this.callParent([cfg]);
   }
});
```